# Is the BEFORE Trigger statement executed before the DDL statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Is the BEFORE trigger statement executed before DDL statements or is it inside a DDL statement?

I'm building a small DBMS and currently developing the DDL, and I'm confused about handling the BEFORE statement.

Here's not a defined behaviour for it:

https://web.csulb.edu/colleges/coe/cecs/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=sql/ddldml.php

Oracle describes the behaviour but not what can come inside the preceding or following trigger or whether they can be DDL statements or not:

https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/oracle-trigger/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"BEFORE" is part of the DDL statement that defines the trigger. It describes when the trigger fires in relation to a DML command on a table: i.e. BEFORE or AFTER the change to the data is actually made. This allows you to validate or modify the new data as it is being applied, or to add or modify dependent data like a child table after the parent table update is complete.

While you can technically embed DDL into the body of a trigger using "execute immediate", it is typically considered very bad practice to do so. Is there a specific use case you are considering for including DDL statements in a trigger?

Comment: Your answer clarifies a lot because for some weird reason I thought the BEFORE Statement was a directive for the CREATE Statement and not a condition verification. I was thinking in enabling chained execution of DDL Statements but this is just experimental. I'm not a fan of having Triggers but people often use them and I was trying to make them a little more flexible.

Comment: "*While you can technically embed DDL into the body of a trigger using "execute immediate"*" - no, you can not because DDL implicitly commits and you can't commit in a trigger.

Comment: Again, not advisable, but you can use an autonomous transaction within a trigger. You can also issue grants - also considered ddl - from a schema or database trigger.